# Java GridBayLayout replacing components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I am trying to delete multiple components in a JPanel using a GridBagLayout

```
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        createAndShowGUI();

        GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel(frame.getContentPane());
        gamePanel.delBlock(0, 0);
        gamePanel.delBlock(0, 1);

        frame.setContentPane(gamePanel);

    }
});
```

This is is the method for deleting a block

```
public void delBlock(int x, int y){

    int location = x * row + y;
    this.remove(location);

    this.revalidate();
    this.repaint();

}
```

As you can see the 2 blocks should be next to one another but this is what i get as a result.

[image]

Comment: You image doesn't appear via the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    gamePanel.delBlock(0, 0);
    gamePanel.delBlock(0, 1);
```

First you remove component at location 0. Then all the components shift 1 position in the Container.

Then you remove component at location 1. However, this the component that was at location 2, before you removed the first component.

Try:

```
    gamePanel.delBlock(0, 1);
    gamePanel.delBlock(0, 0);
```

to reverse the order in which you remove the components.

That is always remove components from the end of the container first.

> As you can see the 2 blocks should be next to one another

I can't tell if you mean "next to" one another in a vertical sense or horizontal sense.

Given that the two components have been removed from the first column, it appears that you are building your grid in column order. That is you add all the components for column 1 and then column 2 and then column 3 etc.

If you want your components to be "beside" one another (in a horizontal sense) then you need to add the components in row order.

Comment: Thank you, you have answered my question! However is there another way which i can remove multiple components without having to worry about reversing the order?

Comment: @AlanYu, glad the answer helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved. You create create a `List` containging the Integer values of the component to be deleted. Then you can sort this List in reverse order. Finally you iterate through the List and remove the components. This is a little more work, but the net result is that you don't need to worry about the order in which you add the Integer values to the List because the sort will make sure they are removed in the proper order.